# How do I enter a special character in SQL connection

Tags: sql-server, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server in Jupyter Notebook. I receive this error because of the '@' in the password. Specific login changed for obvious reasoning.

> (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

```
%sql mssql+pyodbc://dbadmin:myP@ssword@Foray64
```

How can I format this without changing the password? This isn't my software. The vendor has this password hardcoded everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried escaping with backslash character(s) yet?

Comment: Yes, that also failed. I ended up getting the password changed.